# Como faço o selenium webdriver alternar entre as janelas abertas?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Preciso fazer o webdriver navegar entre as janelas abertas. Já tentei:`this.chromeDriver.SwitchTo().Window(chromeDriver.WindowHandles.Last());` mas não consigo usar o Last().

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será que está faltando algum using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente incluir:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Funcionou para o Last() ser aceito, mas quando rodei a aplicação, ele não trocou as janelas, simplesmente foi pra próxima instrução que procurava um elemento na outra janela e não encontrou.

Answer (score 0):

Tente identificar a janela que você precisa usando:

```
foreach (var handle in driver.WindowHandles)
{
   driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
}
```

Após descobrir qual a janela, pode-se chegar nela assim:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1]);
```